# POST results in a HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type response

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I created an API which recovers the deck created by a user and store it in the database but the API gives me a 415 error.
Ising react I would like to use the api to communicate the front-end and the back-end

Thank you for your help :)

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]

    public class DeckController : Controller
    {

        private readonly ILogger<DeckController> _logger;
        private readonly mtgContext _context;

        public DeckController(ILogger<DeckController> logger, mtgContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public OkObjectResult Add([FromBody] Deck deck)
        {
            try
            {
                Deck D = new Deck();
                D.Name = deck.Name;
                D.CreateAt = deck.CreateAt;
                D.User = new User();
                _context.Deck.Add(D);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            return Ok(new
            {
                Success = true,
                returnCode = "200"
            });
        }
    }
```

```
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const deck = useSelector(state => state.cardList.decklist);

    function addDeck() {
        fetch(`/api/Deck`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ Name: name, CreateAt: "2007-07-15", JoinCards: deck })
        })
    }
```

Comment: In your `fetch()` call, you need to set the content-type as well. Try with `headers: { contentType: 'application/json' }`

Comment: I followed your advice but I still have the same error :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> POST results in a HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type response

When I tested with your code, I did reproduce the problem.

Through debug, it is found that in the `fetch` method, the `contentType` needs to be added to the `application/json` format to pass the json data, but there is a problem with your writing.

To sove it, just to change the content of headers in fecth as follow:

```
  headers: { 'Content-Type':  "application/json" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I update the information and I give it to you hoping that it helps you find the origin of the problem.

```
[Route ("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]

public class DeckController : Controller {

    private readonly mtgContext _context;

    public DeckController (mtgContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Add ([FromBody] JsonObject deck) {
        
    }
}
```

```
    function addDeck() {
            const test = JSON.stringify({ Name: name, CreateAt: Date.now(), cardList: deck });
            console.log(typeof(test));
            fetch(`/api/Deck`, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: test,
                headers: { contentType: 'application/json'  }
            })
        }
```

```
System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of reference types without parameterless constructor is not supported. Type 'System.JsonObject'
       at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException_DeserializeCreateObjectDelegateIsNull(Type invalidType)
       at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleStartObject(JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
       at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& readStack)
       at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonReaderState& readerState, Boolean isFinalBlock, ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& readStack)
       at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```